# Check for extrema points on the boundary

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following function:

$$f:\mathbb{\Omega\subset R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x,y):=x^3+2y^2+1$$ where $\Omega=B[0,3]=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x^2+y^2\leq9\}$

Now, the function has a single critical point, $(0,0)$. Let's find the Hessian matrix:

$$\left(\begin{matrix} 
6x& 0\\
0& 4\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Which, evaluated in $(0,0)$, is null, and hence the test is inconclusive. But it's easy to see manually how its a saddle point.

Now its where the problem arises, I know by **Weierstrass** theorem that the function does reach its extrema points, since it's continuous and defined in a compact. I want to check which ones they are, but I have no clue how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check on the boundary of the given area. I think that making $x$ as positive as possible and then as negative as possible will work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying, but I'm not sure how. The boundary is an infinite number of points. Maybe expressing $y$ in terms of $x$ and treating that as a single variable function?

Comment: Remember that the derivative is only for the **interior** critical points, you have to check the boundary separately.

Comment: I think that $x=3, y=0$ for a maximum and $x=-3, y=0$ for a minimum. But yes your idea to write $y^2=9-x^2$ is fine!

Comment: You mean $x^2+y^2\le 9$ on your post or not?

Comment: Oh yes, I do indeed, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check the boundary separately. Since $x^2+y^2=9$ we have $2y^2=18-2x^2$, so that the function is

> $$x^3-2x^2+19,\quad -3\le x\le 3$$

Differentiating gives $3x^2-4x=0\iff x\in \left\lbrace 0, {4\over 3}\right\rbrace$. Checking with the second derivative gives that $0$ is a max and ${4\over 3}$ is a min. Also checking $x=\pm 3$ gives all the possible extreme values.

You can even make a list to find them

$$\begin{cases}
f(0,\pm 3)= 19 & \text{local maxima}\\ 
f({4\over 3},\pm {\sqrt{65}\over 3})= {481\over 27}\approx 17.8 & \text{local minima} \\ 
f(-3,0)= -26 & \text{global minimum}\\ 
f(3,0)= 28 & \text{global maximum}\\ 
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for your help Adam, now it's clear. I like the list method. One more question: If the function was defined in a higher dimensional real space, say $\mathbb{R^3}$, then to check the extreme points at the 2-dimensional boundary, I would have to analyze it as a regular $\mathbb{R^2}$ function? That is, applying the Hessian test, and so on? On even higher spaces, is this process recursively done to find all solutions?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You just keep reducing to the lowest dimension you need to.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Adam ;)